# Python subprocess AttributeError

Tags: python, linux, subprocess

I have the following issue:

```
    try:
        with subprocess.check_call(query):
            return 1
    except ValueError:
        return -1
```

This code runs a shell script and it's working so far. The script returns 0. Nevertheless I got this error:

```
with subprocess.check_call(query):
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__exit__'
```

so there has to be someting wrong with my try/except block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`subprocess.check_call()` returns an int  status code `0`, **not** a context manager. You cannot use it in a `with` statement.

```
return subprocess.check_call(query)
```

Just return the return value of that call. Note that it will not raise a `ValueError` exception either; it'll raise [`CalledProcessError`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CalledProcessError) if the process exits with a non-zero status code.

Perhaps what you really wanted to use was [`subprocess.call()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call).